# How to find remaining files and folders from already deleted applications?

Tags: applications, cleanup, android-9

I see folders `.com.taobao.dp` and `anycast` with some files (about 500Kb) but Taobao and AnyCast applications were deleted a long time ago.

So, is there a way/tool to find such files? (for example by application name or package?)